# Export button in Crystal Report - no action happens when clicked

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-12

I have a web application that uses Crystal Reports 12 to view reports.  Reports view successfully, but when I try to export the report to any format (PDF, Excel, etc.), the export button does nothing.

When I copy the report url and enter it in the browser I get a JavaScript error `object expected` in allinone.js.

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not provide any code, Crystal reports has gotten issues in exporting reports. So I personally recommend getting the latest version.